# How to connect win7 laptops and android device using wifi

Tags: windows-7, home-networking, android

I have two laptops running Windows 7 and one android 1.6 device (apad). All of them support wifi. I have one 3G USB modem. I want to:

1. Connect USB modem to one laptop. I can access internet on this laptop.
2. Connect to other laptop using wifi and share the internet connection. I should be able to access internet on both laptops.
3. Connect my first laptop to android device using wifi. I should be able to access internet on android device also.

How can I setup this network. If required, I can also use ethernet. I have LAN cables and a 8-port Dlink switch.

Note: I can access internet on all three devices by activating Mobile APN on my Samsung Wave mobile phone. But this uses an 2G internet connection (slow speed). I want to do the same using my 3G USB modem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this lifehacker article : [Turn Your Windows 7 PC Into a Wireless Hotspot](http://lifehacker.com/5369381/turn-your-windows-7-pc-into-a-wireless-hotspot).

It describes how you can share your wired Internet access via WiFi.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. And it gave me many other possibilities also. Now I connected almost all wifi enabled devices at my home. Thanks again.