# Connecting an aakash tablet to the internet

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, internet

I have an aakash tablet (android os) and a compaq presario notebook (windows os). I need to connect my tab to the internet. So I tried to make it possible through wifi. For that I created an ad hoc network in my notebook. The following images will show how I created my ad hoc network.

[image: '**Set Up a Connection or Network**' window - '**Choose a connection option**' page]

[image: '**Set Up a Connection or Network**' window - '**Set up a wireless ad hoc network**' page]

[image: '**Set Up a Connection or Network**' window - '**Give your network a name and choose security options**' page]

[image: '**Set Up a Connection or Network**' window - '**Setting up the <name> network...**' page]

[image: '**Set Up a Connection or Network**' window - '**The <name> network is ready to use**' page]

After creating it, I made that network to look for available devices. At once I was able to see a **Waiting for users** message in the **Currently connected to** pane. Then I switched on the wifi in my tab. It scanned for available networks and found my ad hoc. I entered my network password and clicked on the connect button. But there was no significant operation done by the tab to connect to my network. It was doing nothing to connect. Help me connect it to the internet. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This question has been already ansewered [here](https://superuser.com/questions/251509/tethering-on-windows-7), [here](https://superuser.com/questions/701819/using-lapotop-as-hotspot-using-windows-7), [here](https://superuser.com/questions/306090/making-your-windows-7-a-wifi-hotspot-for-android) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/205375/how-to-connect-win7-laptops-and-android-device-using-wifi)

Windows *AdHoc Wireless Network* is used to share Internet Connection between PC's.
Use some *Hotspot Tool* to share your Internet Connection with your Android device. See

- [Connectify](http://www.connectify.me/)
- [VirtualRouter](http://virtualrouter.codeplex.com/)
- [mHotspot](http://www.mhotspot.com/) etc.

Comment: I tried mHotspot. Even now, my tablet is not showing any progress. Is the problem with the tab? How can I solve it?